# How to split rows in pandas with special condition of date?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

```
Code          Date          sales
1             2/2013        10
1             3/2013        11
2             3/2013        12
2             4/2013        14
...
```

I want to convert it into a DataFrame with a timeline, code, and sales of each type of item:

```
Date       Code      Sales1     Code   Sales2
2/2013     1         10         NA     NA
3/2013     1         11         2      12
4/2013     NA        NA         2      14
....
```

or into a simpler way:

```
Date       Code      Sales1     Date      Code   Sales2    .....
2/2013     1         10         3/2013    2      12
3/2013     1         11         4/2013    2      14
```

or even into the simplest way, splitting into many small DataFrames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `concat`with the `groupby` result

```
df.index=df.groupby('Code').cumcount()# create the key for concat
pd.concat([x for _,x in df.groupby('Code')],1)
Out[392]: 
   Code    Date  sales  Code    Date  sales
0     1  2/2013     10     2  3/2013     12
1     1  3/2013     11     2  4/2013     14
```

Comment: Your answer is right. I was stupid to want to split the data in this way cause it included many codes (not 2) so can create thousands of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was stupid to split the data that way, I rethink and solve the problem with the `pivot_table`

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, values = ['sales'], index = ['code'], columns = ['date'])
```

and the result should be like.

```
         sum
 date    2/2013    3/2013     4/2013 ....
 code
 1       10        11         NaN
 2       NaN       12         14
 ...
```